# Why violets die in closed space?

Tags: plant-physiology

I'm going to engage into making florariums (a garden in the bottle). I've heard, that violets die in closed space. Do anyone have an idea, what is the reason for that? Lack of oxygen or CO2 or moisture control issues?

Comment: We also have gardening and landscape SE. You can consider posting this there.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is because of the violets' propensity to collect mould. They seem to like warm, humid space, but in a closed-air type system, it is a breeding ground for mould.

There could be another reason as to why they die, but I would assume it would be an infection.

Comment: Hi!  Welcome to the site! It would improve your answer if you add some reference/source for your answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As far as I know, violets perfectly exist in +20C, is it to warm to breed mould? If that's the point, I guess violets could grow in closed space, provided the mould is tackled (i. e. by chemicals).